# How can I change FontSize in Style of app.xaml using binding? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

[image]

I want to change whole `FontSize (Button, TextBox, Label, etc...)` of my WPF Window if I click buttons like added Capture.

I create Main Project and sub project to develop, and also I use Style in App.xaml (in Main Project) and I want to bind Resources FontSize(in Sub Project) Setter Value, but I can't give DataContext to Application.
In addition, Can't I give reference Model in another sub Project?

Here is part of my code.

**App.xaml** in Main Project (Startup)

```
<Application xmlns:mydata="clr-namespace:Example.Exampl_Data" > ...<mydata:ChangeFontSize x:Key="MyFontKey"/>
```

==> Here is an Error (Can't find Namespace ; i think because it is in another project.)

```
<Style x:Key="LabelTitleStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource MyFontKey.FontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
```

**example.xaml**  in Sub Project

```
<Label x:Name="lb_Reg" Content="TEST" Style="{DynamicResource LabelTitleStyle}"/>
```

**ChangeFontSize.cs**

```
public class ChangeFontSize : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double fontSize=15;
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return fontSize; }
        set { fontSize = value; }
    }

    public ChangeFontSize() { }       

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    public void Increase()
    {
        FontSize += 10;
    }

    public void Decrease()
    {
        FontSize -= 10;          
    }
}
```

**Example.xaml.cs**

```
private void btn_biggerF_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cfs.Increase();
}

private void btn_smallerF_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   cfs.Decrease();           
}
```

Comment: You View (not your Application) needs the ViewModel as DataContext to bind to it's properties.

Comment: 'ChangeFontSize' is ViewModel, isn't it?